# how to display my content in particular div

Tags: jquery

please find this link 
http://www.jsfiddle.net/Mihir/BBDTG/1/

Here i am displaying my html files in a div using `<iframe>`, is there any other way to display those html files in that div without using `<iframe>`...not using ajax also.. if there is no way except ajax..its ok please tell me.. 
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Please check [**server side includes**](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/include.html)

Comment: so.. it is comes under asp.net..!

Answer (score 1):

You can always store a bunch of HTML snippets inside a non-displayed `<div>` and copy the chunks as needed with something like this:

```
$('#content-goes-here').html($('#hidden-chunk').html());
```

You'd assemble it all on the server side using whatever technology is available (possibly server side includes) and then copy the HTML pieces around on the client as needed. You'd have to be careful with `id` attributes inside the pieces of course as `id` attributes should be unique and duplicating pieces of HTML could violate uniqueness.

This is sort of an "AJAX inside a single page without talking to the server" approach.

This isn't a great approach if the HTML chunks are large but maybe it will work for what you need to do; hard to say without more context.

Here's an example to make things clear: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/rQ22T/

Comment: @mu it is worked for only static contents... as like to display only html text etc.. but here i am performing displaying new html pages which contains javascript css and html etc.. got my point?

Comment: @Mihir: Okay, that clarifies things. Sounds like AJAX is going to be your best bet; anything else will end up being a poor and cumbersome simulation of standard AJAX techniques.

Comment: . thank you.. till now i am not entered in ajax thats y i am not prefer ajax.. when i come to ajax then i wl definitely ask u if there are any doubts.. :)

Comment: AJAX is very easy to use with jQuery, learning it right away would be a good idea and shouldn't take very long.